# Передача параметра через ссылку в подключаемый JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт, который подключается к двум страницам, но выполнение должно отличаться в зависимости от страницы..
Возможно ли при подключение, в ссылке указать параметр, а после его прочитать и изменить выполнение..

Допустим:

Две страницы, **page_a** и **page_b** и js файл, по ссылке `/script.js`

Далее подключение выглядит так `<script src="/script.js?page_a">` или `?page_b` соответственно странице.

А в `js` файле уже условие, к примеру:

```
param = параметр в ссылке;
if(param === 'page_a')
  alert('Ты на странице A');
else if(param === 'page_b')
  alert('Ты на странице B');
```

---

Возможно ли такое и как реализовать? (хотя б где глянуть).

---

Или проще закостылить на проверке по ссылке страницы, типо через `location.href`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо тега `script` пришлось написать `div`, а то SO ругается, мол 404. Чтобы все работало в твоем случае просто поменяй `div` на `script` и не забудь изменить селектор в коде тоже. Можно также находить тег скрипта, присвоив ему `id`, чтоб уже наверняка не ошибиться.

```js
let param = $("div[src^='/script.js?']").attr("src").match(/^.+?\?(.*)$/)[1];

$("body").html(param);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div src="/script.js?page_a">
```